# Plugin for coupon codes

Tags: magento2, plugin, interceptor

I have added a plugin which should be triggered when a coupon code is applied. Sadly nothing happens, no errors too.

Where did I go wrong?

```
<?php

namespace Zygis\TestModule\Plugin;

class CheckoutCouponApply {

    public function beforeSet(\Magento\Quote\Model\CouponManagement $subject, $cartId, $couponCode)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $logger        = $objectManager->create('\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface');
        $logger->debug('test before set');
    }

    public function afterSet(\Magento\Quote\Model\CouponManagement $subject, $cartId, $couponCode)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $logger        = $objectManager->create('\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface');
        $logger->debug('test after set');
    }
}
```

And obviously I got it registered in Zygis\TestModule\etc\frontend\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\CouponManagement">
        <plugin name="CheckoutCouponApply" type="Zygis\TestModule\Plugin\CheckoutCouponApply" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Sadly you are on the wrong path for coupone code. What is your primary goal for plugin?

Comment: I want to change the error message for an expired coupon code later. However now I just want to see the plugin being fired. Please elaborate why I'm on the wrong path?

Comment: I have found the right way. I created a preference instead of plugin.

Comment: Did you found the solution using plugin way?

Answer (score 0):

If anybody stumbles across this in the future, make sure your di.xml file for the REST endpoints resides in the etc directory, not the etc/frontend directory.

**BAD**

> Vendor\Module\etc\frontend\di.xml

**GOOD**

> Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml